# Moving element from position to position with jquery/angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Well the problem is quite simple...
I have an array of movies div (image and desc) written with a simple ng-repeat...
Now when i choose one of them i want to do the following (A game of positions i suppose):

1)I want to take out that element from the array and with a smooth animation to enlarge it to some other place in the screen, without breaking the order of that array.

2)when i choose another film, i want that one that i selected before to get back to where it was, following my newly selected film to take the space of the one before it:

here is a simple practice page i created so someone can dig it more:
http://single.org.il/

(just press on one of the categories up there,a list of movies will appear down at the bottom of the page, the black screen in the middle is where i want my selected film to enter, it's allready happening but it breaks, a lot)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend including the selection state as part of the data model, then binding the view based on the selection data.  The important points being:

- Track the selected item as part of the $scope, and selection state as part of the item data
- Filter selected items out of the navigation list
- Bind the detail view to the selected item

I created a simplistic jsfiddle to demonstrate the concept, http://jsfiddle.net/ZLvQD/1/.  The key code points include the filtered navigation list:

```
<div ng-controller="ListController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:{isSelected:false}" 
      ng-class="{selected: item.isSelected}" ng-click="select(item)">
      {{item.desc}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-hide="!selectedItem">
    <hr/>
    The selected item is:
    <p class="selected">{{selectedItem.desc}}</p>
  </div>
```

the data model including selection state:

```
$scope.itemList = [
    {
        "desc": "Item A",
        "isSelected": false
    },
...
```

and the controller tracking selection state:

```
$scope.selectedItem = null;
$scope.select = function(selectedItem) {
    // Deselect existing
    if ($scope.selectedItem) {
        $scope.selectedItem.isSelected = false;
    }
    // Select new
    selectedItem.isSelected = true;
    $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;
};
```

I'm afraid I do not know anything about the animation part.

Comment: It's the animation that gives me the hard time, but that's very good to know, thank you, i kinda solved it usings just scaleX and scaleY though...